# How to get IE8/9 active tab html source by C#

Tags: c#, .net, html, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to create a program in C# in Visual Studio which would acquire html source of a current opened (or selected, or all) tab(s) in Internet Explorer 8/ (prefered) 9. I am tired of copying by - browser-> View Source, alt+a, alt+c, program -> alt+v
Anyone got an idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's no easy solution for this I think Maybe you should continue copy and pasting. Anyway, this is what I found surfing the web:  (http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/Q_23767759.html)

```
{   // used spy++ to get the names of these guys
            // get the handle to the IE toolbar
            childHandle = FindWindowEx(IEwindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "WorkerW", IntPtr.Zero);
            if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //get the handle to the address bar on IE
                childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ReBarWindow32", IntPtr.Zero);
                if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    // get a handle to comboBoxEx32
                    childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        // get a handle to combo box
                        childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", IntPtr.Zero);
                        if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                        {
                            //get handle to edit
                            childHandle = FindWindowEx(childHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", IntPtr.Zero);
                            if (childHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                            {
                                // now to get the URL we need to get the Text - but first get the length of the URL
                                int length = SendMessage(childHandle, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);
                                length += 1;    // because the length returned above included 0
                                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(length); // need stringbuilder - not string
                                int hr = SendMessage(childHandle, WM_GETTEXT, length, text); // get the URL
                                strURL = text.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Now that you have accessed the url, send an HTTP Get Request you will get the site source in plain text.

Comment: This is a really nice piece of code - So if You can ask explorer for an url, why not ask it for the source?

Comment: Futhermore ie is devided in Frame Tabs (from spy++) - each window Frame Tab has a window TabWindowsClass which has a Window Shell DocObject View which has a window Internet Explorer_Server

Comment: @Miszka: The best I could find uses something called Band Objects. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/415f8b61-7db4-48ab-ab5c-71721afac718 Which is hosted on CodeProject...Which is down for a few hours. Check it out when you can. Hope you make it. and let me know if you did.

Comment: @Kamyar This code is very version dependent, unfortunately. It may work in one version of IE, but it'll never work in all.

Comment: It is possible, I am working on it, will give full code in some time. This code helped me very much! Thank You indeed

Comment: I'd appreciate if you post a new answer if you found anything useful.